# Independent resource for creating external style sheets?

Tags: css, stylesheet

Is there any independent resource, where I can place CSS code, to use it's URL in <link> tag?

Comment: What google say? (-:

Comment: why Optimus Prime need this ? there will be another Transformers ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You can use Amazon web services to host images and css files. It will provide you a url to put with in a  tag and it will also give you a url to put within image tags if thats something you are interested in. There are also other places.

Here is an example image hosted on aws: https://s3.amazonaws.com/pr-otp/email_folder3/OTP_021518_01.jpg

Here is an example of css hosted on aws: https://s3.amazonaws.com/dgpr/About-Us/css/styles.css

AWS link: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

You can also use drop box.

Here is a guide you can use: https://feed.mikle.com/support/using-dropbox-host-css-files/

You can also use google drive.

Here is a guide for google drive: 
https://thenextweb.com/google/2013/02/05/google-drive-now-lets-developers-share-hosted-websites-by-storing-html-javascript-and-css-files/